# how to get confirmation in HTML page after submitting a form

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

Hi I have a HTML file that contains a form and a php file which recieves the html form data.
I want to show the confirmation message in html file (within a div container) after execution of php file. Tried a lot searching everywhere, but still didnt get the answer.

Here is my html form (enquiry.html)

```
<div class="form-body">

                                    <form method="post" action="/">
                                        <span id="MasterInner_lblName">Your Name</span>
                                        <input name="MasterInner_txtName" type="text" />
                                        <span id="MasterInner_lblEmail">Your Email</span>
                                        <input name="MasterInner_txtEmail" type="email" />
                                        <span id="MasterInner_lblMobile">Your Mobile</span>
                                        <input name="MasterInner_txtMobile" type="text" />
                                        <span id="MasterInner_lblCity">Your City</span>
                                        <input name="MasterInner_txtCity" type="text" />
                                        <span id="MasterInner_lblCity">Remarks</span>
                                        <textarea name="MasterInner_txtRemarks" /></textarea>
                                        <button type="button" name="MasterInner_submit" value="Submit" id="submitform" Class="form-button" />Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div> <!-- Form ends -->
                                <div id="confirmID">test for form submission</div>
                                <script>
                                    $("#submitform").click(function() {
                                        //code
                                        $.post("enquiry.php", {
                                        MasterInner_txtNamePost: MasterInner_txtName,
                                        MasterInner_txtEmailPost: MasterInner_txtEmail,
                                        MasterInner_txtMobilePost: MasterInner_txtMobile,
                                        MasterInner_txtCityPost: MasterInner_lblCity,
                                        MasterInner_txtRemarksPost: MasterInner_txtRemarks
                                        },function(data) {
                                          alert("Form submitted");
                                          document.getElementByID(confirmID).innerHTML = "Submitted";
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
```

I am unable to understand, what to write in php to set the "Thanks for submitting" message in html page.

Enquiry.php file

```
<?php
```

//error_reporting(0);

```
//if($_POST["w32apideftype"]!="")
//{     
    //echo $_POST["key"];
     // Function for filtering input values.
    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data =stripslashes($data);
        $data =htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    //echo "ths i stest";
    // Initialize variables to null.
    $s_name="ABC";// Sender Name
    $s_email="feedback@abc.com";//Sender's Email
    $r_email="xyz <xyz.com>";//Recipient Email
    $subject1="My subject";//Subject of mail
    //Form Data vars
    $f_name =""; 
    $f_email =""; // Sender's email ID
    $f_message =""; // Sender's Message
    $f_phone="";//Sender's Phone
    $f_city="";//Sender's city
    //Form data vars end

    $nameError ="";
    $emailError ="";
    $f_phoneError="";
    $f_cityError="";
    $subjectError ="";
    $f_messageError ="";
    $successMessage =""; // On submittingform below function will execute.
    if(isset($_POST['MasterInner_submit'])) { // Checking null values in message.
        //echo "Submit button pressed";

        if (empty($_POST["MasterInner_txtName"])){
            $nameError = "Name is required";
            //echo $nameError;
        }
        else
         {          
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$f_name))
            {
                $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
            else
            {
                $f_name = test_input($_POST["MasterInner_txtName"]); // check name only contains letters and whitespace
                //echo $name;
            }
        } // Checking null values inthe message.
        if (empty($_POST["MasterInner_txtEmail"]))
        {
            $emailError = "Email is required";
            //echo $emailError;
        }
        else
        {
            $f_email = test_input($_POST["MasterInner_txtEmail"]);
            //echo $email;
        } // Checking null values inmessage.
        if (empty($_POST["MasterInner_txtRemarks"]))
        {
            $f_messageError = "Message is required";
            $f_message="No Additional message";
            //echo $f_messageError;
        }
        else
        {
            $f_message = test_input($_POST["MasterInner_txtRemarks"]);
            //echo $f_message;
        } // Checking null values inthe message.
        if (empty($_POST["MasterInner_txtMobile"]))
        {
            $f_phoneError = "Genuine phone is required";
            //echo $f_phoneError;
        }
        else
        {

            $f_phone = test_input($_POST["MasterInner_txtMobile"]);
            //echo $f_phone;
        } // Checking null values inmessage.

        if ($_POST["MasterInner_txtCity"]=="Not Selected")
        {
            $f_cityError = "city is required";
            //echo $f_cityError;
        }
        else
        {
            $f_city = test_input($_POST["MasterInner_txtCity"]);
            //echo $f_city;
        } // Checking null values inmessage.

        if( !($f_name=='') && !($f_email=='') &&!($f_phone=='') &&!($f_city==''))
        { // Checking valid email.
            if (preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$f_email))
            {
                $email=str_replace(",","",$f_email);

                $header1  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $header1 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                $header1 .= 'To: '.$r_email."\r\n";
                $header1 .= 'From: '.$s_name.'<'. $s_email .'>' . "\r\n";
                $header1 .= 'Cc:' . "\r\n";
                $header1 .= 'Bcc:' . "\r\n";


                /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
                //$msg = wordwrap($msg, 70, "\r\n");
                $msg1 = '<html><head><title>Enquiry</title></head>
                    <body><table style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;border:3px solid #e0781f;"bgcolor="#dededc" align="center" width="500"><tr><td colspan="2"><h1>'.$f_name.' sent a Enquiry</h1></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$f_name.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>E-mail: </td><td>'.$f_email.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Phone: </td><td>'.$f_phone.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>city: </td><td>'.$f_city.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Message: </td><td>'.$f_message.'</td></tr></table>
                    </body></html>'; 
                /* Send the message using mail() function */
                //echo "message1: - $msg and message 2 : - $msg1";


                if(mail($s_email,$subject1,$msg1,$header1))
                {
                    $successMessage = "Message sent successfully.......";
                    echo"Thank You";
                    header("location:".$_POST["w32apideftype"]);
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                $emailError = "Invalid Email";
                //echo"Invalid Email";

            }
         }
    }
//}
```

?>

Pls help, to get this work.

Comment: Please post your php file as well

Comment: well if you are using ajax to submit the details of the form to php you can wait for the callback status and then display a success message -- you could also echo back some data from php to ajax to say whatever -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- search on that page (Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you can easily do this by adding a click event and post method. For example:

```
document.getElementByID("id").click(function() {
                    //code
                    $.post("enquiry.php", {
                    MasterInner_txtMobilePost: MasterInner_txtMobile,
                    MasterInner_txtCityPost: MasterInner_lblCity,
                    MasterInner_txtRemarksPost: MasterInner_txtRemarks
                    }, function(data) {
                      alert("Form submitted");
                      document.getElementByID("confirmID").innerHTML = "Submitted";
                    });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your valuable reply. I tried this but dont know why nothing is happening. I am sharing my updated code with jquery script and enquiry.php. Please see if this can work. Thanks

Comment: Well first of all, you need to make sure that the id's are correct. The first "id" should be the id of your button. After the alert, I have a confirmID in case you want to change the text of something. If you do, make sure to add quotes around it and point it to the exact spelling of the id of your tag you want to change. Another thing to keep in mind is your php file must be in the same directory of your html page. If it's not you need to give the exact url (http://www.example.com/enquiry.php). Also, in my method above I added the word "Post" to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your php file **enquiry.php** before the php closing tag.

```
header("Location: confirmation.html");
exit;
```

**Note:** Confirmation page should be same as your **enquiry.html** you can just replace the form with your message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but creating another page with message will not workout. Need to display the message on the same page